# Couldn't get the total amount of each employee by id&&dept

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm having difficulty with my query. First, let me discuss to you the system flow.

My client owns a firm, and inside the establishment she also has a mini-grocery & canteen) for her employees to take their snacks/meals.

The employees doesn't have to pay as they order, instead they'll just list down all the items/meals they took from either grocery or canteen together with their names and during payday(monthly due) the total amount of the items that each employee had taken will be subtracted from their total salary.

Ex1. John Carter has taken a Popcorn from the Grocery worth $45.00 and by lunch he took a Sandwich along with Caesar Salad from the Canteen which is worth $125.00. So in his payday, a total of $170.00 would be deducted from his salary.

In my database I had 3 tables. One named `sales` to which all the items,quantity,unit and amount_sale from the grocery were being stored.
Ex. `Biscuit`,`10`,`pack`;
`Coffee Sachet`,`5`,`pack`; etc.
So basically, on my `stock` table I have `item_name`,`quantity`,`unitOfmeasurement`,`amount_sale`
Note: that the `amount_sale` is the number of sales for the grocery.
For the next table I have, `serve` to where all the foods inventory from the Canteen where being stored. I also have `item_name`,`quantity`,`uom` and ofcourse `amount_serve`; to fill this up.

and ofcourse, the `customer` table where tables of the customer such as `name`, etc where being stored.

This is my query to get the total amount that would be deducted to each employees salary.

```
SELECT c.*, SUM(sale.amount_sale) AS a, SUM(serv.amount_serve) AS b
   FROM customer AS c INNER JOIN sales AS sale ON
      sale.customer_id=c.customer_id INNER JOIN serve AS serv ON
      serv.customer_id=c.customer_id GROUP BY c.customer_id ORDER BY c.cdept ASC;
```

With this query, the output is this:

Figure 1:

> John Carter should be deducted $170.00
>   Jane Hartley should be deducted $130.00

The output was just fine and as expected, but my client wants next is to get the total value of each employee per department. To further explain this matter, here's my illustration.

Figure 2 (Expected Output):

> John Carter- Accounting Dept. should be deducted $170.00
>   Jane Hartley - Accounting Dept. should be deducted $130.00
>   Employees in Accounting Dept. has a Total Amount Due of $300.00
>
> Bob Oswald-Marketing Dept should be deducted $260.00
>   Marie May Stewart- Marketing Dept. should be deducted $100.00
>   Employees in Marketing Dept. has a Total Amount Due of $360.00

With the query I presented to you above I got the result I needed for Figure 1. Though right now am having difficulty to do the Figure 2. I tried to alter my query by adding `and c.cdept` in `GROUP BY c.customer_id` But it only displays the output.

Figure 3:

> John Carter-Accounting Dept. should be deducted $300.00
>   Meaning his own due was being merged with Jane Hartley's.

Any idea how would I get the output for Figure 2? What would I add on my query to get it, or is there anything wrong with my query?

TABLE STRUCTURE FOR:

-SALES-
id,customer_id,sale_date,qtysold,amount_sale.
-SERVE-
serve_id,customer_id,servedate,qtyserve,amount_serve.
-CUSTOMER-
customer_id,customer_name,cdept.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be very helpfull.

Comment: But sir @CoderofCode I already did include sample data and my expected output in the forms of Figure 1 to 2.

Comment: That's not sample data that's only one example how you want to get it. Sample data might include the 5-10 rows of data which satisfy all your conditions and expected output is what do you expect as output.

Comment: I see.I would like to paste a picture to show the structure of my tables for sales, serve and customer. But I don't know how. I was just told that html table tag doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Though you describe the scenario, we cant imagine the table structure properly. I guess Sales table contains all sales related stuffs. Probably, this query might be useful for you

> select c.dept_name, sum(sale.amount_sale) from customer as c inner join sales as sale on c.id = sale.customer_id group by c.dept_name;

Updated:
I guess, you need to add logic to your PHP code instead of MySql Query. You can use your First Query for displaying Figure2 results but you need to change your PHP code according to that.